# Pontwise product of sequences diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have a homework problem that says, prove if $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n>0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n=\infty$, then the $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_nb_n=\infty$. I can understand intuitively why this is true. If a sequence diverges, then for some real number $R$ the terms are greater than $R$ after a certain point in the sequence. So if you multiply a converging (positive) sequence by a diverging sequence, then all terms should diverge.
I'm just having trouble formalizing my ideas, I would appreciate any help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=L>0$, we have that $a_n>\frac{L}{2}$ for all $n>n_1$. Using this, can you show that for every $M\in\mathbb R$ there exists $n_0\in \mathbb N$ with $a_n\cdot b_n >M$ for all $n>n_0$?

Comment: So an>L/2, and bn>B for all B after a certain point in both of the sequences. As in the comment below, you can multiply (an)(bn)>BL/2 for all B so the product diverges. But why are you allowed to say this? Is this an application of the product rule? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why am I allowed to say what? $a_n>\frac{L}{2}$ follows directly from the definition of the limit of a sequence, $b_n>B>0$ follows directly from the definition of a strict divergent sequence. And of course you can then say $a_n\cdot b_n> \frac{L}{2}\cdot B$ because every factor is bigger than $0$. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes thank you, that's what I was missing, the part where every factor is bigger than 0 so the inequality holds true. I thought you were applying the product rule with limits but I was confused because I thought it only applied to converging sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Write $A = \lim a_n$. Then there is some $N$ such that $a_n > A/2$ for all $n > N$.

Now, choose any $B > 0$. Since $b_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, there is some $M$ such that $b_n > B$ for all $n > M$.

So, if $n > \max(M,N)$, both conditions hold: $a_n > A/2$ and $b_n > B$. Therefore, since all of these quantities are positive, it follows that $a_n b_n > AB/2$. Since we can do this for arbitrarily large $B$, we conclude that $a_n b_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.